# how to match the last value of array in mongo db?

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2, moped

I'm trying to fetch some data from db.  Here is my query which I have tried. My issue is that my out has dc_id which is an array. I'm using $eleMatch, which returns 1st matching element. what if I want to match last value?

```
tasks = $production_task_service.where({:pid=>5, :out=>{"$elemMatch"=>{:dc_id=>1}}})
```

my record structure looks like:

```
{"bid"=>nil,

 "out"=>
  [{"ts"=>2014-04-25 07:31:16 UTC,
    "uid"=>1,
    "dc_id"=>2,
    "a"=>
     {"expected"=>{"FALSE"=>"1", "TRUE"=>"0"},
      "notes"=>"asdas",
      "isit"=>"asdas",
      "datesit"=>""},
    "step"=>13,
    "g"=>1,
    "duration"=>54.467903445,
    "rejected"=>true,
    "rej_at"=>1409550263.9896142,
    "sample"=>3,
    "rej_by"=>3},
   {"ts"=>2014-09-01 09:51:22 UTC,
    "uid"=>1,
    "dc_id"=>1,
    "a"=>
     {"expected"=>{"FALSE"=>"0", "TRUE"=>"1"},
      "notes"=>"121212",
      "isit"=>"dsf",
      "datesit"=>"Sat Apr 14 1212 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"},
    "step"=>13,
    "duration"=>10.105335834,
    "rejected"=>true,
    "rej_at"=>1409566392.574016,
    "sample"=>4,
    "rej_by"=>1},
   {"ts"=>2014-09-03 10:11:40 UTC,
    "uid"=>5,
    "dc_id"=>2,
    "a"=>
     {"expected"=>{"FALSE"=>"0", "TRUE"=>"1"},
      "notes"=>"kranthi",
      "isit"=>"kranthi",
      "datesit"=>"Tue May 26 1987 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"},
    "step"=>13,
    "duration"=>20.881858257}],
 "pid"=>5,
 "rand"=>0.09438103628922767,
 "res"=>[],
 "sample"=>
  [{"id"=>3}, {"id"=>4, "for_review"=>true, "rejected"=>true, "rej_by"=>1}],
 "state"=>"completed",
 "id"=>"52c430556771518721000036"}
```

Comment: @Neil-lunn can u provide me the link where it has answer. It will be helpful for me if you can do that

Comment: The link is the duplicate question shown at the top of your question. Read the answer there. The approach is essentially to reverse the order that you are storing the elements of the array.